# does android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED requires users permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am implementing HeyZap and it requires me to add

```
<receiver android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.PackageAddedReceiver">
 <intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="package"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Do these lines in `AndroidManifest.xml` require user permission for update or will update my Google Play users automatically?
Usually user permission is not a problem. But Admob voluntaristicaly changed the rules without prior notification and force me to use "New Admob" and I wish to move as much users as possible from Admob.

Does following permission is required?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_ADDED" />
```

There is only BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED permission in SDK and HeyZap does not mention that permission but some users on StackOverflow mention it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to add permission. Read [How can I get Actions: PACKAGE_REMOVED and PACKAGE_ADDED](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/aX5-fMbdPR8) thread for more.

---

You can try one more thing is, add `exported` and `enable` option as `true` for `Receiver` into Manifest, and then try.

Like

```
<receiver android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.PackageAddedReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
```

Comment: Thank You. But my main question/concern is "Will user be prompted for permission or they would be updated automatically if I add <receiver> only" ?

Comment: @Max No the user will not be prompted by application for permission. They will be updated automatically.